# The bottombarview in android with kotlin does not display text under unselected items

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout

the bottombarview below displays the android text: tooltipText only if the element is selected in the bottombarview if it is not selected the text is not displayed, how can I make it visible even if the element is not selected!

[image: bottom bar image]
**bottom_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_nav_selector"
        android:title="Profilo"
        android:tooltipText="Profilo"
        android:visible="true" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_nav_selector"
        android:title="Veicoli"
        android:tooltipText="Veicoli"
        android:visible="true" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bottle"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bottle_nav_selector"
        android:title="Info"
        android:tooltipText="Info"
        android:visible="true" />

</menu>
```

**FragmentProfile.xml:**

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemIconSize="28dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

Comment: Did you try updating your material library in gradle because app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" should have taken care of it.

Comment: No at with version?

Comment: No at with version?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' try it with this version of android material library.

Comment: I have try but not works

Comment: try removing these android:tooltipText="Info"
        android:visible="true" lines

Comment: I have try but this not work